# Upgrading to Java 11 from Java 8 - package sun.util does not exist

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I'm trying to migrate an application from Java 8 to Java 11. When I try and build the project in IntelliJ I get a `package sun.util does not exist` error?

Any ideas on what's up?

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle [**bought**](https://www.oracle.com/sun/index.html) sun in **2010**!

Comment: Depending on sun.* classes is always dangerous and fragile as they can change or be removed at any time. javac has been emitting a warning about this for many releases. Which sun.util.* class are you using? Just wondering if there is a standard API that you could use instead.

Comment: I was using a `ResourceBundleEnumeration` to implement our own `ResourceBundle`. But I've worked out a way to do it with `new Vector<>(keySet).elements()` which seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Packages `com.sun.*` and `sun.*` hold internal stuff, and should not be used by thirdparty applications (like yours probably) in general case.

Since in java 9  the module system has been introduced, now Oracle "protect" these packages even in compile time.

So the obvious way is to get rid of this dependency in your code.
Why do they protect? Because they leave the right to themselves to change this stuff, its considered internal as I said.

*Addition:*

You can try (I do not recommend) to apply some "resolution" tools found in [this great article](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/) (Read "Illegal Access To Internal APIs" chapter), but as the author of this article states, the most straightforward way is to stop using these packages in your code, so consider it as the first bet.