# error: package sun.net.smtp is not visible

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

We are moving some old code to java11.We are creating a smtp client. The coe compilation fails when we use java11.

```
error: package sun.net.smtp is not visible
[javac]  sun.net.smtp.SmtpClient SMTP = new sun.net.smtp.SmtpClient(SMTP_SERVER);
[javac]                            ^
[javac]   (package sun.net.smtp is declared in module java.base, which 
does not export it)
```

looks like smtp package support is removed from the java11. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Regards,
Akj

Comment: Packages `com.sun.*` and `sun.*` are internal packages. The recommendation is to replace them; [Java 11 package sun.util does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847089/upgrading-to-java-11-from-java-8-package-sun-util-does-not-exist)

Comment: The old code is wrong. Change it to use the public JavaMail API.

Comment: @Ammy you can refer to the below example which i've given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaMail API to send email to get this sorted. Go to below link and download the .jar file and add to your project. If not you can add it as a maven dependency.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7

A sample code to talk to SMTP server and send email as per below.

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@abcmail.com"));
message.setRecipients(
  Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("to@abcmail.com"));
message.setSubject("Mail Subject");

String msg = "This is a sample email ";

MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
mimeBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

Your configurations can be done with a Java Properties object

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.abcmail.com");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.abcmail.com");
```

Comment: FYI, JavaMail 1.4.7 is over 6 years old.  The current version is [1.6.3](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: A valuable addition to the same. javax.mail has moved to  javax.mail-api . The current version of javax.mail-api is 1.6.2 as per the available in maven repo. All of you can refer to the below link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api

Answer (score 1):

You should use JavaMail, a Java API for sending and receiving emails via SMTP, POP3, and IMAP.

First, have a look at Oracle docs about sending mail in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html)

The sample code below is extracted from the Oracle docs and illustrate how you should send email using the [JavaMail API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "my-mail-server");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

try {
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom("me@example.com");
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                      "you@example.com");
    msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
    Transport.send(msg, "me@example.com", "my-password");
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
}
```

Also, note that to send a mail with Java Mail you need a valid SMTP server and an account in that server.

Comment: Is it possible to export the packages in java11 by adding compiler parameters. Looks like changing the code is not feasible for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: To avoid conflicts, you'll just need to change the code. Also, look into the Java Module System. Have a look at https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/
Please let us know of any challenges you face while migrating to Java 11.