# Upgrading JDK8 to OpenJKD 11: sun.security.rsa

Tags: java

As part of a legacy application being upgraded to `openJDK 11`, I'm having difficulties refactoring bits of code relying on `sun.security.*` since the compilation fails with:

```sh
  package sun.security.rsa is not visible
 (package sun.security.rsa is declared in module java.base, which does not export it to the unnamed module)
```

Given the below code snippet:

```java
// Read private key which is BASE64 encoded
byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decode(config.getPrivateKey().getBytes());
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

// Illegal Access To Internal APIs
RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl) privateKey;
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey.getModulus(), rsaPrivateKey.getPublicExponent()));
...
```

Does anyone know how i could replace the **last two lines** of above code without relying on packages from `sun.security.*`? `RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl` is using internal api `sun.security.*` break in openJDK11.

Comment: Is there a reason you're casting that to `RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl`  instead of the interface `RSAPrivateCrtKey` ?  One is an implementation detail and the other isn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading to Java 11 from Java 8 - package sun.util does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847089/upgrading-to-java-11-from-java-8-package-sun-util-does-not-exist)

Comment: amature hour on my behalf . thanks @Powerlord

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to replace the `Impl` class with the interface that it implements; i.e.

```
RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey;
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(
        new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey.getModulus(), 
                             rsaPrivateKey.getPublicExponent()));
```

since both `getModulus()` and `getPublicExponent()` are declared in the interface.

For what it is worth, this code never *needed* to depend on an internal implementation class in the first place.